# Unity GooglePlayGames LoadScores always returns nothing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to fetch the top score from a leader board using Google Play Games, however it doesn't return anything. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
    public int WorldRecord()
{
    int topScore = 0;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        GPGSIds.leaderboard_quick_fire_scores,
        LeaderboardStart.TopScores, 1,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (LeaderboardScoreData data) =>
        {
            topScore = (int)data.Scores[0].value;
        });

    return topScore;
        
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores` runs asynchronous and executes the passed action after having finished.

Your method, however, doesn't wait until that request actually finished and thereby simply returns the default value `0` already before the `LoadScores` actually finishes and provides a valid result.

You should probably rather use some kind of callback like e.g.

```
public void WorldRecord(Action<int> onResult)
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        GPGSIds.leaderboard_quick_fire_scores,
        LeaderboardStart.TopScores, 1,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (LeaderboardScoreData data) =>
        {
            onResult?.Invoke((int)data.Scores[0].value);
        });        
}
```

And then pass a callback what should happen when the result is ready like e.g.

```
WorldRecord(topScore => 
{
    Debug.Log($"Top Score: {topScore}");
});
```